# How to make jquery available to sprockets using Webpacker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I've just started experimenting with Webpacker within an existing app.

From all that I've read, my understanding is that Webpacker and Sprockets can co-exist, and that libraries compiled in Webpacker (e.g., jquery) can be made available to Sprokets via global variables.

But all my jquery in the asset pipeline are raising `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $`

Have I misunderstood, or is there a bug in my code?

I've added jquery

`yarn add jquery`

and assigned the variables in environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');

const webpack = require('webpack');
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
}));

module.exports = environment;
```

this works:

```
#javascript/packs/application.js
$(function () {
    console.log('Hello World from Webpacker via JQUERY');
});
```

this does not

```
#assets/javascripts/application.js
$(function () {
    console.log('Hello World from Sprockets via JQUERY');
});
# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
```

What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Why are you using both webpack and sprocket? Use either one?

Comment: Thanks @ArupRakshit, I’m using both because (1) from what I’ve read I thought this was possible and (2) moving to Webpacker will be a process, during which it will be useful to have both available

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable question for apps transitioning from 5.2 to 6.0, and there's no good story in Webpacker today for engines or gemified assets.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the end it is relatively easy to expose jQuery to global from within webpacker. But finding documentation on how to do this was very difficult! Hopefully, this can save someone else a search.

Add expose-loader

```
yarn add expose-loader -D
```

And then add the following configuration to config/webpack/environment.js

```
environment.loaders.append('expose', {
    test: require.resolve('jquery'),
    use: [{
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: '$'
    }, {
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: 'jQuery',
    }]
})
```

I was then able to remove jquery from the asset pipeline, restart the server, and all my remaining jquery functions within sprockets continue to function as expected.

Comment: Great answer. This needs much more attention. You should accept your answer too.

Comment: In webpack, the `ProvidePlugin` approach automatically performs an `import Library from "library"` statement on each file in your pack, with the only real benefit is that you save typing.  It does NOT actually add anything to the global space.  However, when you use `expose-loader`, it DOES expose these libraries to the global space, which would be `window.LIBRARY_NAME`.  Once I understood that difference, it made everything a lot simpler.

Comment: You also need to add this line `require('expose-loader?$!jquery')` into your pack (e.g. `app/javascript/packs/application.js`), for jQuery to become available globally.